# Asking about sorting or ordering results from a search engine by relevancy in php/Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, elasticsearch, relevance

I have a search engine based on multiple select options that the user can enter a lot of option and the search engine fetch the database to get the the results of  arrays that entered in the the select options but I need to make this code to fetch and get ordered the results by the most relevant
so this is the code :

```
<?php
//doctors.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing", "root", "");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Symptome4 FROM tbl_customer ORDER BY Symptome4 ASC";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

?>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href=".\css\bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <link href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="find-bar">
    <header id="header">
      <div class="overlay overlay-lg">

      </div>

      <nav>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="logo">
            <h1>Oxygenta</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="links">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="file:///C:/Users/yosse/OneDrive/Desktop/AAST/Year%204/Semester%208/Graduation%202/Oxygenta/homepage2/index2.html">Home</a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="#">Diagnosis</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="file:///C:/Users/yosse/OneDrive/Desktop/AAST/Year%204/Semester%208/Graduation%202/Oxygenta/3in1/doctors.html">Doctors</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href=" file:///C:/Users/yosse/OneDrive/Desktop/AAST/Year%204/Semester%208/Graduation%202/Oxygenta/3in1/find-doctors.html">Home Doctors</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href=" file:///C:/Users/yosse/OneDrive/Desktop/AAST/Year%204/Semester%208/Graduation%202/Oxygenta/3in1/find-nurse.html">Nurses</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="file:///C:/Users/yosse/OneDrive/Desktop/AAST/Year%204/Semester%208/Graduation%202/Oxygenta/Ticket/ticket.html">Help</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="file:///C:/Users/yosse/OneDrive/Desktop/AAST/Year%204/Semester%208/Graduation%202/Oxygenta/login.html" class="active">Sign Out</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="header-content">
        <div class="container content">
          <div class="column-1">
            <h1 class="header-title">Find Your <br /> Favorite Doctor</h1>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="search_box">
                <div class="search_btn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
                <input type="text" class="input_search" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <img src="./img/doctor_PNG16022.png" class="img-bar" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </header>
    <section class="services section">
      <div class="container left">
        <div class="section-header">
          <h2 data-title="">Symptoms</h2>

         
      </div>
      </div>
     
    </section> 
<div class="container">
      
      <select name="multi_search_filter" id="multi_search_filter" multiple class="form-control selectpicker" style="width: 50%;">
    <option value="Runny Nose">Runny Nose</option>
    <option value="Sore Throat">Sore Throat</option>
    <option value="Headaches">Headaches</option>
    <option value="Sneezing">Sneezing</option>
    <option value="High Temperature">High Temperature</option>
    <option value="Hoarse Voice">Hoarse Voice</option>
    <option value="Difficulty Swallowing">Difficulty Swallowing</option>
    <option value="Drooling">Drooling</option>
    <option value="Weak Voice">Weak Voice</option>
    <option value="Coughs">Coughs</option>
    <option value="Dry Throat">Dry Throat</option>
    <option value="Difficulty Speaking">Difficulty Speaking</option>
    <option value="Throat Pain">Throat Pain</option>
    <option value="Fever">Fever</option>
    <option value="Difficulty Breathing">Difficulty Breathing</option>
    <option value="Loss Of Smell">Loss Of Smell</option>
    <option value="Loss Of Taste">Loss Of Taste</option>



      </select>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_country" id="hidden_country" />
      <br />
     
        <table class="table table-striped ">

          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>




      </section>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  load_data();
  
  function load_data(query='')
  {
    $.ajax({
      url:"fetch.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{query:query},
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('tbody').html(data);
      }
    })
  }

  $('#multi_search_filter').change(function(){
    $('#hidden_country').val($('#multi_search_filter').val());
    var query = $('#hidden_country').val();
    load_data(query);
  });
  
});
</script>
```

and this for fetch.php

```
<?php

//fetch.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing", "root", "");

if($_POST["query"] != '')
{
 $search_array = explode(",", $_POST["query"]);
 $search_text = "'" . implode("', '", $search_array) . "'";
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM tbl_customer 
 WHERE Symptome4 IN (".$search_text.") OR  Symptome2 IN (".$search_text.") OR Symptome1 IN (".$search_text.") OR Symptome3 IN (".$search_text.") OR Symptome5 IN (".$search_text.") 
 ORDER BY DiseaseID DESC ";
}
else
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer ORDER BY DiseaseID DESC";
}

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

$total_row = $statement->rowCount();

$output = '';

if($total_row > 0)
{
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '
<table><tr><td>
            <div class="cards"></td>
            <td><div class="card-wrap">
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="card-content z-index">
                  <img src="./img/nurse.png" class="icon" alt="" />
                  <h3 class="title-sm">'.$row["DiseaseName"].'</h3>
                  <h5 style="text-align: left;">

                  '.$row["Symptome1"].'
                  </p>
                  <p>
                  '.$row["Symptome2"].'
                  </p>
                  <p>
                  '.$row["Symptome3"].'
                  </p>
                  <p >
                  '.$row["Symptome4"].'
                  </p>
                  <p >
                  '.$row["Symptome5"].'
                  </p>
                  <a href="file:///C:/Users/yosse/OneDrive/Desktop/AAST/Year%204/Semester%208/Graduation%202/Oxygenta/3in1/find-nurse.html" class="btn small">More Info</a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

  ';
 }
}
else
{
 $output .= '
 <tr>
  <td colspan="5" align="center">No Data Found</td>
 </tr>
 ';
}

echo $output;


?>
```

and this is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkF5q.png)

Comment: are you using `elasticsearch` or `mySql` ? because i cant see any code related to Elasticsearch.

Comment: _by the most relevant_ What is relevant? Order of the selects, longest match, first in the database?

Comment: yes by the longest match or the most matched with the selected options @Michel